# Expected primary-expression before '{' token error

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, dev-c++, c++03

The code below runs properly with `Eclipse` but when I run it on `Dev C++ IDE` I get this error:

```
City.cpp:6: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
```

*City.h*

```cpp
#include <string>
 
using namespace std;
  
#ifndef CITY_H
#define CITY_H
    
class City
{
    public:
    City();
    string arrCity[10];
};
   
#endif // CITY_H
```

*City.cpp*

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "City.h"
 
City::City()
{
  arrCity[10] = {"Tbilisi", "Batumi", "Kutaisi", "Gori", "Poti"};        
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [get rid of the `using namespace std;` habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, i am still getting same error..

Comment: Yes, that's a tangent subject. songyuanyao's answer is the correct one though -- if it doesn't work, we're missing some information from you. What version and flags of your compiler are you using?

Comment: My Dev C++ uses mingw32 v3.4.2

Comment: Yeah, that's apparently from 2004, so C++03. I'm adding the tag. Please tag your questions carefully when you're using an older version of C++ :)

Comment: Please show the version number of your C++ compiler.

Comment: Don't use C-style arrays, prefer std::vector or std::array.

Comment: In your case (C++03), you have to initialize each array member separately, that is a[0] = x, a[1] =  y. Or, even better, upgrade to C++11.

Answer (score 3):

`arrCity[10] = {"Tbilisi", "Batumi", "Kutaisi", "Gori", "Poti"};` doesn't do what you expected. It's trying to assign `arrCity[10]` (i.e. a `std::string`) by a braced initializer list; that won't work. And it's getting out of the bound of the array.

Note that array can't be assigned directly, you can use member intializer list to initialize it like:

```
City::City() : arrCity {"Tbilisi", "Batumi", "Kutaisi", "Gori", "Poti"}
{
}
```

or use default member initializer:

```
class City
{
    public:
        City();
        string arrCity[10] = {"Tbilisi", "Batumi", "Kutaisi", "Gori", "Poti"};
        // or
        string arrCity[10] {"Tbilisi", "Batumi", "Kutaisi", "Gori", "Poti"};
};
```

Note that both the above solutions needs C++11 supports, otherwise, you might need to assign every element one by one in the constructor's body.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help, unfortunately it doesn't work. also it returned new error 

City.cpp: In constructor `City::City()':
City.cpp:4: error: expected `(' before '{' token
City.cpp:4: confused by earlier errors, bailing out

Comment: @GoranZooferic [DEMO](http://rextester.com/VANOK33865) Does your compiler support C++11?